# Who is the Hübsch gambit named after?

Tags: history, gambits

According to [Lichess](https://lichess.org/opening/Queens_Pawn_Game_Hubsch_Gambit), the Hübsch gambit starts with 1. d4 Nf6 2. Nc3 d5 3. e4:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. Nc3 d5 3. e4
```

[This article](http://www.belkaplan.de/chess/bdg/diemer/budzinski_ueber_bdg_und_huebsch-gambit_en.html) states:

> Second, despite being named in honor of an unknown player, Hübsch, who achieved a spirited victory in 1922 with the White pieces over the renowned Saviely Tartakower [...]

Who was this Mr(s) Hübsch, does anyone have any further information?

*Edit*: [this article](http://bdgpages.blogspot.com/2009/05/hubsch-such-pretty-little-gambit.html?m=1) claims that his/her name starts with "E".

*Edit*: [Another page](https://www.wtharvey.com/mcmxxii.html) claims that the first name starts with an "F".

*Edit*: the video description of [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8_mtNV5mMlE) cites a book and the following text:

> On December 20, 1922, an unknown young man entered the chess room at the Café Central, walked straight up to Grandmaster Tartakower, who was sitting idly by, and challenged him to a game of chess for a high stake. (DeepL translation)

Answer (score 4):

Not a definitive answer, but going through google nGram viewer produces a publication showing the actual game in [British Chess Magazine](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_British_Chess_Magazine/Y6FJAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22h%C3%BCbsch%22%20gambit&pg=PA146&printsec=frontcover), 1923. There the notation is E. Hubsch, and the annotation states that it is abridged from *Kagan's Neueste Schachnachrichten*.

I could not find online versions of the Kagan volume(s), however there are several volumes of that available through various antique resellers. There appears to be at least one collection partially available online [through google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=kd43AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA168&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), but I am not conversant in German to be able to know if this is relevant or not. Archive.org may also have some resources in their scan collection.